# Is there any way to "hide" a View to Screen Readers, like "aria-hidden" does in HTML?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, screen-readers

I need that the Screen Readers like VoiceOver don't recognize (or don't "read") this `<View>`.

For example, let us suppose that we have a simple App with this template code: `<View><Text>Events</Text></View>`.

When I run this App, I can see "Events" on the screen. Then if I enable VoiceOver, he says : "Events". Well, I want that he cannot say "Events". In other words, I want that he cannot read this Events. Just like "aria-hidden" does in HTML.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can hide a view along with its descendants from screen readers in React Native. The property for that is platform dependent.

`accessibilityElementsHidden` (iOS)

> A Boolean value indicating whether the accessibility elements contained within this accessibility element are hidden.
>   For example, in a window that contains sibling views A and B, setting accessibilityElementsHidden to true on view B causes VoiceOver to ignore the elements in the view B. This is similar to the Android property importantForAccessibility="no-hide-descendants".

`importantForAccessibility` (Android)

> In the case of two overlapping UI components with the same parent, default accessibility focus can have unpredictable behavior. The ‘importantForAccessibility’ property will resolve this by controlling if a view fires accessibility events and if it is reported to accessibility services. It can be set to ‘auto’, ‘yes’, ‘no’ and ‘no-hide-descendants’ (the last value will force accessibility services to ignore the component and all of its children).

For example:

```
<View
  accessibilityElementsHidden={true}
  importantForAccessibility="no-hide-descendants"
>
    <Text>This text won't be read by the screen reader</Text>
</View>
```

Here is the source for more details on Accessibility: [React Native - Accessibility](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about setting `accessible={true}` prop to the parent view?

It will make the whole parent a single group and you will not be able to focus children using voice over.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's answer does the job. Alternative, there is an `accessible={false}` prop. See docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#accessible).

Answer (score -2):

To show/hide a view in react-native conditionally, use a separate render function to check the condition:

```
render: function(){
    return (
        {this.renderOnCondition()}
    );
},
renderOnCondition: function(){
    if(whateverCondition){
        return (<View />);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need the <View> always visible. Only I need that the Screen Readers like VoiceOver don´t recognize (or don´t "read") this view. For example, there are a <View> with a <Text>Events</Text>. I can see this View, but I want that a blind cannot "see" this <View> when he uses VoiceOver.

Answer (score -4):

use aria-hidden="true" on the element. This will prevent a screen reader from reading the element. It should also prevent the element from being selected when swiping while on mobile devices.

Answer (score -5):

Try `view.setVisibility(HIDDEN);`

Comment: Sorry, i am using a ReacNative <View> and I cannot find any documentation about this .setVisibility(HIDDEN).  

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#content  

Even so I try it in my App, but it doesn´t work:  

`code  
componentDidMount() {  
    this.refs.View.setVisibility("hidden");  
  }
`

Comment: Set visibility: You can hide or show views using setVisibility(int)

Comment: There's no such thing as View.HIDDEN